# Raster layer statistics QGIS 3.4 doesn't give information about pixel count

Tags: raster, qgis-3, zonal-statistics, statistics

I created a plugin in QGIS 2 AND I used the `qgis:rasterlayerstatistics` , I could get the 'COUNT' information : pixels number, but when I migrate my plugin to version 3.4 I found out that this information (COUNT) is not available anymore .

is there any other way to have raster statistics about pixels number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Raster layer unique values report` tool instead. When the interface loads, make sure to create an output for the *Unique values table* parameter as this would contain the count information:

[image: Raster layer unique values report interface]

The output of this table will be an `.html` file which can be loaded from the Results Viewer (from the menubar: `Processing > Results Viewer`) and should look something like the following:

[image: Results Viewer]

Comment: thanks, it's working

Comment: @Namoat - Most welcome, glad it helped :)